# How my image could get the ImageView Size

Tags: java, android-studio, android-viewpager, imageview

I got my Image from the server(PHPMyAdmin)and put on a ViewPager but When I passed this Image to next Activity to ImageView:

ViewPagerAdapter.JAVA:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem (  ViewGroup container, final int position ) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    SliderUtils utils = sliderImg.get( position );

    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.imageView2 );
    final EditText placa = (EditText)view.findViewById( R.id.placa5 );

    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance( context ).getImageLoader();
    imageLoader.get( utils.getSliderImageUrl(),ImageLoader.getImageListener( imageView,R.mipmap.ic_launcher, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert ) );

    view.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            //if(position == 0){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Slide Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap b=imageView.getDrawingCache();
                Intent i = new Intent(context, TouchDraw.class);

                BitmapHelper.getInstance().setBitmap( b );
                i.putExtra("EXTRA_PLACA", String.valueOf( placa ) );

                imageView.setImageBitmap( b );
                context.startActivity(i);
```

And the Image stays like that on my TouchDraw.java:

[image: click here to see my image]
TouchDraw.java:

```
    paint = new Paint();

    CreateBitmap();
    GetBitmapWidthHeight();
    bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap1, bitmap1.getWidth()+ BitmapSize * 2, bitmap1.getHeight()+ BitmapSize * 2, true );
    bitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bm.getWidth(),
            bm.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    );
    DrawCanvas();

    imageView0.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

public void CreateBitmap(){
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("image_url",0);

    bitmap1  = BitmapHelper.getInstance().getBitmap();

}
public void GetBitmapWidthHeight(){

    width = bitmap1.getWidth() + BitmapSize * 2;
    height = bitmap1.getHeight() + BitmapSize * 2;

}
public void DrawCanvas(){

    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap2);

    canvas.drawColor( Color.CYAN);

    canvas.drawBitmap(
            bm,
            0,
            0,
            null
    );

}
```

So, How Can I fix this thing, because When I used Images from drawable it worked very well, How I can fit the image or zoom, or scale that? If it's not possible,
How I get just the URL from an image by another activity? I put the images in a ViewPager, because there's a lot of images to appear when the user selects a vehicle on activity(that's the reason just appear a specifics types of trucks or other vehicles).

Comment: Why are you passing whole image.. Just pass URL and load it again.

Comment: How I get just the URL from an image by another activity? I put the images in a ViewPager, because there's a lot of images to appear when the user selects a vehicle.

Comment: try adding this to your imageview  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` if that wont solve your problem  then be specific to your problem.

Comment: This not working yet, I just don't know what's happening with my project, but I think I'll tryna get the imageUrl from the activity shows all images before It's going to my TouchDraw(The drawPaint ACtivity, by the way).